# Python Function returns wrong value

Tags: python

```
periodsList = [] 
su = '0:'
Su = []
sun = []
SUN = ''
```

I'm formating timetables by converting

```
extendedPeriods = ['0: 1200 - 1500',
    '0: 1800 - 2330',
    '2: 1200 - 1500',
    '2: 1800 - 2330',
    '3: 1200 - 1500',
    '3: 1800 - 2330',
    '4: 1200 - 1500',
    '4: 1800 - 2330',
    '5: 1200 - 1500',
    '5: 1800 - 2330',
    '6: 1200 - 1500',
    '6: 1800 - 2330']
```

into `'1200 - 1500/1800 - 2330'`

- su is the day identifier
- Su, sun store some values
- SUN stores the converted timetable

  ```
  for line in  extendedPeriods:
    if su in line:    
      Su.append(line)

    for item in Su:
      sun.append(item.replace(su, '', 1).strip())

    SUN = '/'.join([str(x) for x in sun])
  ```

Then I tried to write a function to apply my "converter" also to the other days..

```
def formatPeriods(id, store1, store2, periodsDay): 
  for line in extendedPeriods:
    if id in line:    
      store1.append(line)

  for item in store1:
    store2.append(item.replace(id, '', 1).strip())

  periodsDay = '/'.join([str(x) for x in store2])  
  return periodsDay
```

But the function returns 12 misformatted strings...

```
'1200 - 1500', '1200 - 1500/1200 - 1500/1800 - 2330',
```

Comment: You should give your variables different names, you are bound to confuse them with these names.

Comment: What was the input you provided exactly to get those malformed strings?

Comment: formatPeriods(su, Su, sun, SUN)

Comment: Using your `formatPeriods` function with the inputs from the top of your posts, it works just as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `collections.OrderedDict` here, if order doesn't matter then use `collections.defaultdict`

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> dic = OrderedDict()
for item in extendedPeriods:
    k,v = item.split(': ')
    dic.setdefault(k,[]).append(v)
...     
>>> for k,v in dic.iteritems():
...     print "/".join(v)
...     
1200 - 1500/1800 - 2330
1200 - 1500/1800 - 2330
1200 - 1500/1800 - 2330
1200 - 1500/1800 - 2330
1200 - 1500/1800 - 2330
1200 - 1500/1800 - 2330
```

To access a particular day you can use:

```
>>> print "/".join(dic['0'])   #sunday
1200 - 1500/1800 - 2330
>>> print "/".join(dic['2'])   #tuesday
1200 - 1500/1800 - 2330
```

Answer (score 1):

This is your general logic:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)

for i in extended_periods:
    bits = i.split(':')
    d[i[0].strip()].append(i[1].strip())

for i,v in d.iteritems():
   print i,'/'.join(v)
```

The output is:

```
0 1200 - 1500/1800 - 2330
3 1200 - 1500/1800 - 2330
2 1200 - 1500/1800 - 2330
5 1200 - 1500/1800 - 2330
4 1200 - 1500/1800 - 2330
6 1200 - 1500/1800 - 2330
```

To make it function for a day, simply select `d[0]` (for Sunday, for example):

```
def schedule_per_day(day):

    d = defaultdict(list)

    for i in extended_periods:
        bits = i.split(':')
        d[i[0].strip()].append(i[1].strip())

    return '/'.join(d[day]) if d.get(day) else None
```